# Setting up and testing UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use ncy-angular-breadcrumb, which uses ui routes.  I have a module set up to house the ui routes:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('configurator.uiroutes', ['ui.router', 'ncy-angular-breadcrumb']);

    app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    label: 'Series'
                }
            });
    }]);

})();
```

I have this test to see if the route works:

```
describe('Configurator UI Routes', function () {

    beforeEach(module('configurator.uiroutes'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.router'));

    var $state, $rootscope, state = '/';

    // Inject and assign the $state and $rootscope services.
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$state_, _$rootScope_) {
        $state = _$state_;
        $rootscope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    //Test whether the url is correct
    it('should activate the state', function () {
        $state.go(state);
        $rootscope.$digest();
        expect($state.current.name).toBe('home');
    });
});
```

Which produces this error:

```
Error: Could not resolve '/' from state ''
```

I'm just not getting the UI Router and either how it works, or what it's supposed to do.  I just want to grab parts of the url and pass that info to ncyBreadcrumb, but I can't even get the base URL to work.

Any pointers or help would be awesome!

Edit:  I've gotten the test to pass by replacing '/' with 'home' in the test.  My bigger question is: is there a way to test that when the URL '/' is hit, that the state.current.name becomes 'home'.  In my use of the app, this doesn't appear to be happening, and I'm hoping that the unit test can help tell me why.

This is a single page application, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Error is enough self explanatory, as you asked `ui-router` to redirect on `/` state using `$state.go`

Basically `$state.go` which asks for state name rather than `url`.

```
var $state, $rootscope, state = 'home'; //<--changed from `/` to `home`
```

Comment: Cool.  I was thinking that go was mocking a URL.  The test passes now.  Is there a way to test a URL navigation?  Currently in my site when I'm at '/' it doesn't seem to work until I navigate to the next page, then 'Series' shows up, but not until then.

Comment: I'm not looking to navigate by state, I want to navigate by URL and define/check the state.

Comment: @spuppett I think you could do that just by redirecting to url using $location service like `$location.path('/')` then do `$rootscope.$digest();` to update the state.. That's it..